# Access to my sub directories using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to rewrite my url first one is working fine now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /oneday/index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to rewrite url but now I want to access my sub directories and my directories exists like this `Oneday/files/pdf-generation/dock-receipt-PDF24032015.pdf` and for this my code is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /oneday/files/pdf-generation/path$1
```

and my complete code of htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /oneday/index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ /oneday/files/pdf-generation/path$1
```

but the second one is not working for me. How could I do this and `Oneday` is my project directory name.

Now first url create this link `http://localhost/oneday/bookings` and now I want to access my `PDF` files `http://localhost/oneday/files/pdf-generation/dock-receipt-PDF03242015.pdf`

Comment: I correct my code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target 2nd rule only for existing files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Oneday/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Oneday/files/pdf-generation/path/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ files/pdf-generation/path/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello `Mr. anubhava` your code is not working for me.

Comment: my url is `http://localhost/oneday/bookings` when I click at `anchor tag` its show popup and then I click at button then the url show in another tab `http://localhost/onedayfiles/pdf-generation/dock-receipt-PDF03242015.pdf` and error is `PAGE NOT FOUND
Sorry! The page you requested either does not exist or you may not have sufficient previlages to view it. Click here to go to the home page.`

Comment: its my writing mistake I checked it again but error is same.

Comment: `http://localhost/oneday/` this is my project directory path and `http://localhost/oneday/files/pdf-generation/dock-receipt-dock-receipt-PDF24032015.pdf` this is my full path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73678/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3833682).

Comment: `Mr. anubhava` are you there? can you you help me for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250729/typeahead-bootstrap-auto-suggestion-for-ajax-function