# typeahead bootstrap auto suggestion for ajax function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using `typeahead` auto suggestion for my application but the problem is ajax function exists in `bookingAjaxFunc` function and `bookingAjaxFunc` code is

```
function bookingAjaxFunc(url, bookingId, jsonCall) {
     switch(jsonCall) {
          case 'Add':
               values = $('.booking-form').serializeArray();
          break;
          case 'autoSuggestion':
               values = {bookingId: bookingId, jsonCall: jsonCall};
          break;
     }
     $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: values,
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
               switch(jsonCall) {
                    case 'Add':
                         console.log(data);
                    break;
                    case 'autoSuggestion':
                         console.log(data);
                    break
               }
          }
     });
}
```

this is my ajax function which is working fine in insert, update, delete and other cases but now I want to call this function in `typeahead` how could I do this? and my `typeahead` function is working fine in predefined values but now I want to call my `bookingAjaxFunc` I couldn't figure out where to call my function, and remember this function is copy from an example and I paste it here as it as.

```
function substringMatcher(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substrRegex;

        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                matches.push({ value: str });
            }
        });

        cb(matches);
    };
}

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];

$('.autoSuggestion').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'states',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

The `bookingAjaxFunc` function which create for my ajax call so where I use my this code for passing values to my function and use my case

```
var url = $("#do").val();
bookingAjaxFunc(url, '', 'autoSuggestion');
```

I also try to add `remote` below `source` but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: No one is here to solve my problem?

Comment: There is lot of code in question. If you reduce it down so that someone can understand it better then you may get good answers though I am not typeahead/bootstrap person.